# How can I convert a column has multiple values to list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with three columns.

```
df = pd.read_csv('doc.csv')


document    year    Keywords           
     1     2018     Appliance Interaction; Intrusive Load Monitoring; Appliance Identification            
     2     2018      wireless networks; Learning algorithms; operator recommendations           
     3     2019      Natural Language; Crowdsourcing; Natural Language; Sensemaking
```

Data:

```
{'document': [1, 2, 3],
 'year': [2018, 2018, 2019],
 'Keywords': ['Appliance Interaction; Intrusive Load Monitoring; Appliance Identification',
  'wireless networks; Learning algorithms; operator recommendations',
  'Natural Language; Crowdsourcing; Natural Language; Sensemaking']}
```

What I want to do is to convert the column (Keywords) into a list like following

```
X = [Appliance Interaction, Intrusive Load Monitoring, Appliance Identification, wireless networks, Learning algorithms, operator recommendations, Natural Language, Crowdsourcing, Natural Language, Sensemaking]
```

and save this list into a separate CSV file

Comment: `df['keywords_lst'] = df['Keywords'].str.split('; ')` Or if you want one list for all rows then `one_big_lst = '; '.join(df['Keywords']).split('; ')`

Comment: try:

`items = [row.split(';') for row in df['Keywords']]

Comment: @ It_is_Chris yes i want one list for all rows

Answer (score 2):

You could split on `"; "` + `explode` and convert to list:

```
X = df['Keywords'].str.split('; ').explode().tolist()
```

Output:

```
['Appliance Interaction',
 'Intrusive Load Monitoring',
 'Appliance Identification',
 'wireless networks',
 'Learning algorithms',
 'operator recommendations',
 'Natural Language',
 'Crowdsourcing',
 'Natural Language',
 'Sensemaking']
```

Comment: @Corralien thanks :-)